# findMeetingTimes does not work when setting activityDomain to "work" and isOrganizerOptional to true

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to find meeting times that work with people in other timezones and do not care if the meeting is in my working hours or not (but I do still want to be mindful of others working hours).  Which is why I want to set myself as optional when finding meeting times.  However, *findMeetingTimes* always returns no results with an empty reason of "unknown" when I do this.

Request:

```
"timeConstraint": {
    "activityDomain": "work",
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2018-09-24T20:00:00.000Z",
          "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2018-09-24T23:00:00.000Z",
          "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "meetingDuration": "PT1H",
  "isOrganizerOptional": true,
  "minimumAttendeePercentage": 0,
}
```

always returns

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
    "emptySuggestionsReason": "Unknown",
    "meetingTimeSuggestions": []
}
```

I can change *activityDomain* to `unrestricted`, and get results back, however, that does not solve the problem I am looking to solve.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to find a meeting time at between `2018-09-24T20:00:00.000Z` and `2018-09-24T23:00:00.000Z`.

Based on my research and test, if we set `work` value for the `activityDomain`, it will return Suggestions are within the user's work hours which are defined in the user’s calendar configuration and can be customized by the user or administrator.

And according to [this official document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_findmeetingtimes#request-body), the default work hours are Monday to Friday, 8am to 5pm in the time zone set for the mailbox.

So if we want find a meeting time between `2018-09-24T20:00:00.000Z` and `2018-09-24T23:00:00.000Z`, we should set the activityDomain as `unrestricted`

Comment: I am trying to solve for this scenario:  

I want to meet with my team in India.  I know I am scheduling a meeting outside my working hours, but I want to make sure I only get meeting results back that are during my India's team working hours.  Don't I need to keep `activityDomain` set to `work` and `isOrganizerOptional` to `true` to make this happen?

Comment: I think you can set `work` value for the `activityDomain`.